# Get Instagram Ad accounts associated with a Facebook user account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve Instagram Ad accounts the are associated with a given Facebook user ID, NOT necessarily linked to a Facebook Page, using the Facebook Graph API. I have seen the endpoints `/instagram_accounts` and `/page_backed_instagram_accounts`, but they only apply to Instagram accounts that are associated with a Facebook page.

Is this something that is possible?